# diversify my solr results

Tags: solr

I would like diversify the results that solr gives back.
Let's assume that this is my schema.

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="domain" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

For the domain field, there are currently 3 types (google, yahoo, bing) that are stored in there.

Whenever I do a query, the top results from Solr are mostly from Yahoo domain. If I want to mix up the top results from all these 3 domains, how should I do it?

Comment: Can you be more clear? I understand that you want results from all three domains. But on what basis do you want them to be ordered?

Comment: @GonnaBeNerdSomeday - The top results for each domain should show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [grouping (aka Field collapsing)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing). You can in fact group results by domain (`groupfield=domain`) and configure how many results you want to have back for each group (default=1, `group.limit=10` for instance).

Comment: Accepted! Grouping makes pagination becomes tricky. Let say I have 3 groups. Each group has 4 results. Each query returns 4 * 3 = 12 results. For the search result page, I have to show only 10 results. There are 12 - 10 = 2 results that I'm not showing. If the customer paginates and clicked on the next 10 results, I have to set group.offset=1(or whatever is the appropriate page). Now those 2 results that I didn't show earlier are gone. How do we solve this problem? The best way is to force grouping to return 10 total results MAX. Can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this pagination problem you can use the parameter **group.format=simple** which gives you the grouped result in traditional response format.

The request URL may look something like this,

```
<ip>:<port>/context-root/select?q=*:*&group=true&group.field=domain&group.format=simple
```